# Active Directory (AD) account getting rejected below is the error

Tags: active-directory, identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

While creating Active Directory (AD) account for User it is giving below error

"Could not create user as it did not meet the Password Policies set on the target system"

I have checked in logs and also there has been no password update/change in AD.

Please help me on this

Comment: Also make sure that the generated password does not have reserved words or parts similar to the username.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code for creating the account?

Comment: Check the password policies on the target machine and create the same in OIM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced similar error and in the diagnostics log I see the complete details about Active Directory password policy. you left with two options to handle this:

1. You need to generate OIM User's password such that it aligns to the password policy of AD
   OR
2. you need to set different password while creating AD account for each user as per AD password policy.

Option 1 is preferred as it will be a smooth transaction with all passwords in sync which will help while doing SSO.